# Today we fell off the first page of 'Hottest proposals' at Area 51 is there anything we can do to get back on there?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed we have fallen off the first page of 'Hottest Proposals' at Area 51.  We've been slowly sinking down the list for a week or more, yesterday we were at the bottom.  Is there anything we can do to 'get hot' again?  I think being on the first page especially near the top helps us out.

Comment: At the moment, we are again on the first page, with several other proposals after it on the first page. Which tells me that the place in that list is probably quite volatile.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't think area 51 is getting us any significant numbers of visitors. It's a low traffic site mostly only visited by people who have been pointed their at a specific proposal.

Things like google searches and HNQ get us far more traffic and we may have dropped off the peak but we still heave pretty healthy figures on both of those.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a more or less educated guess: The hotness of a proposal is mostly determined by Area 51 activity regarding this proposal, i.e., people visiting the proposal page, asking example questions, committing to the proposal, etc.. As we are in public beta now, the activity shifted from Area 51 to the actual site, which is where it belongs.

This is nothing to worry about. In fact, you may have noticed that only three of the many many betas (including [about ten, who only need their design finished to graduate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237472/where-have-the-site-self-evaluations-gone#comment778914_237588)) are on the first page of Area 51 hotness – and all of those are rather young.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm not sure how this hotness is calculated.

The main problem is the overall activity of this site. There is no need to be alarmist but it stagnated in the last week and and now our numbers are slowly decreasing.

Visitor per day peaked at 3000 a week ago maybe and now we are at 2700. It is still good, but there seems to be a trend here. Unless I'm wrong, it's a average for 37 days, not the number of visits for a particular day.

Comment: And our questions/day keep falling too.

Comment: I think the question is talking about an Area 51 page (didn't previously know about "hottest proposals"), not the "hot questions" list.  I don't know if they would have similar issues; A51 plays to a different audience, I suspect.

Comment: I misunderstood the question completely then. The fact that we have Taoism proposal above us with only 2 followers is really weird.

Comment: I was tempting to delete this answer as it's answering the wrong question but the second two paragraphs do still apply to this question, you may want to edit the answer :)